# rhel + disk util is very high , what is the impact for long term

Tags: redhat, iostat, sar, vmdk, utilization

we have backup server with rhel version 7.2

server is VM machine , and OS disk is VMDK disk

disk used space is around - 50% , and from smartctl we not see problem

as we can see from follwing details
the disk util is very high sometimes even reached 100%
we can see also high pressure from reading side

regarding the util values , we think disk cant be helthy for a long time when util is around `90%-100%`

but apprititae to get your feedbacks / notification about this

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               4.00     0.00 3197.00    3.00 45856.00    12.00    28.67     2.92    0.92    0.92    2.67   0.30  94.50
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              10.00    11.00 3160.00   51.00 57068.00   248.00    35.70     3.33    1.05    1.03    2.39   0.30  97.00
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               2.00    30.00 2988.00   62.00 71208.00   500.00    47.02     3.93    1.30    1.26    3.11   0.32  97.40
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              15.00    29.00 2777.00   36.00 67748.00   260.00    48.35     7.20    2.62    2.61    3.69   0.34  94.60
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              20.00     6.00 2648.00   18.00 79044.00   100.00    59.37     7.00    2.65    2.63    5.44   0.35  94.30
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              17.00    14.00 2173.00   23.00 60388.00   148.00    55.13     5.74    2.73    2.72    3.13   0.39  84.60
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              20.00     0.00 2164.00    0.00 68856.00     0.00    63.64     6.48    3.09    3.09    0.00   0.39  84.10
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              15.00     0.00 1817.00    2.00 62424.00     9.00    68.65     5.90    3.35    3.35    2.50   0.47  85.70
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              80.00     0.00 2772.00    0.00 74056.00     0.00    53.43     6.60    2.30    2.30    0.00   0.32  87.90
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              13.00     0.00 4049.00    0.00 103024.00     0.00    50.89    13.04    3.26    3.26    0.00   0.25 100.00
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              13.00     0.00 3274.00    8.00 82548.00    64.00    50.34    12.73    4.08    4.08    4.12   0.30  99.80
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              11.00     0.00 3006.00    2.00 105880.00     8.00    70.40     9.51    3.24    3.24    2.50   0.32  96.00
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              25.00     0.00 2587.00    1.00 92080.00     4.00    71.16     8.56    3.25    3.25    2.00   0.31  81.10
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              37.00     0.00 3472.00    0.00 108932.00     0.00    62.75    11.94    3.48    3.48    0.00   0.28  96.70
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is crossposted https://superuser.com/questions/1775443/rhel-disk-util-is-very-high-what-is-the-impact-for-long-term

Comment: @Romeo , if you can please do not , because I not sure what is the site that fit for my Q

Comment: David, have you read the rules for this site? https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic